# What does it mean for DataFrame.ix to be deprecated?

Tags: python, pandas, deprecated

Suppose I use `DataFrame.ix` in some code.

Does the fact that it's deprecated mean that at some point in the future, I'm going to update pandas, and then a little bit later, the stuff using that code will mysteriously start to break because they decided that finally, they were going to actually remove `ix`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the basic idea of deprecation. The library's maintainers are letting you know now that they plan to stop supporting `ix` (e.g., fixing bugs in it), and may very well remove it in the near future. As long as it's deprecated, you have a window of opportunity to change your code to use other alternatives (such as `loc` and `iloc`), on your own terms, before you're forced to do so when pandas breaks "under your feet".

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Pandas doesn't explicitly define their deprecation policy the way [the Python stdlib](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/) and [NumPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.deprecations.html) do.

But they do keep track of all past, ongoing, and planned deprecations in [#6581: DEPR: deprecations from prior versions](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6581) and [#13777: DEPR: deprecations log for removed issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13777), where they say:

> We try to keep these for three major versions as actual deprecations. e.g. deprecate in 0.17, 0.18 & 0.19 get the warning, removed in 0.20.

There are similar comments specifically on [#14220: DEPR: 0.21 deprecations master issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14220), which includes [#14218: DEPR: deprecate .ix](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14218)/[#15113: DEPR: deprecate .ix in favor of .loc/.iloc](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/15113).

Some deprecated features are kept around even longer. And, if you search #6591 for `.ix`, you'll see that this is one of them. #15113 is scheduled for removal in 1.0, not 0.24.

So, what this means is:

- `.ix` will probably be removed in some future version, currently scheduled for 1.0.
- There will probably be no improvements or fixes to `.ix` ever again.
- There are already better replacements for it as of at least 0.21.

But that isn't set in stone. For example, if a truly critical bug in `.ix` is discovered that nobody knew about last year, they might decide to fix that bug—or to drop the feature sooner than planned. Or, if it turns out that some use of `.ix` is 18x slower with `.iloc` and there's no good workaround, they might revoke the deprecation until they can come up with something better.

All that being said, if you look at the historical list, it seems pretty rare for a deprecation to not go according to plan.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, deprecated here means that the attribute or method has been removed from the newer versions. Hence, it is advised to avoid them in your code to avoid future issues.

Comment: This is incorrect. 'Deprecated' in software means that further use is "discouraged." As I understand it, this generally means that *there is no guarantee that this feature will be supported, or even will exist, in future releases.* 

However, while this is the pattern, this is still rather nebulous, so I'm looking for people more familiar with the pandas project to understand their intent with this word.

Comment: Hmm.. this is interesting. Thanks for sharing. Still though, this is for standard modules (pandas is not a standard module), and this is for modules (ix is not a Python module).

Comment: While @extremeaxe5 isn't _quite_ right, this answer is still wrong. "Deprecated" doesn't have to mean that the attribute has been removed from any newer versions, and it doesn't mean that in this case, The latest Pandas tree still hasn't removed it, and it isn't scheduled for removal until 1.0.

Comment: @abarnert This is is no way aggressive. But in what way am I not quite right?

Comment: I think that's the point Aditya Lahiri was making with the link to PEP 4 is that "deprecated" in software means more than just "discouraged", and, if so, that's probably right, so if you want to be pedantic, your first sentence isn't quite right. But your next sentence qualifies it well enough. And trying to nail down the exact connotations of what "deprecated" means across the world of software too precisely is probably pointless anyway.